# google-cloud-composer BigQuery Cross Dataset load

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer, airflow

I am trying to run a simple select query(from biqquery) and load the result set in another bq table using Composer. However, I am getting an error in the last line of the code.

Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/es_tc_etl_wkf_mtly.py] invalid syntax (es_tc_etl_wkf_mtly.py, line 47)

Code :

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'es_tc_etl_wkf',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Job monitoring dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20))

# priority_weight has type int in Airflow DB, uses the maximum.
t1 = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq_recent_questions_query',
        bql="""
        select * from bigquery.table.`projectid`.dataset_id.table_A;
        """,`enter code here`
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        destination_dataset_table=dataset_id.table_B)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `enter code here` that is not assigned to any recognized parameter. `bql` is already [deprecated](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator), it is suggested to use `sql`. Also your entire dataset in the query statement should be enclosed in back ticks (`).

> bql (Can receive a str representing a sql statement, a list of str
> (sql statements), or reference to a template file. Template reference
> are recognized by str ending in '.sql'.) – **(Deprecated. Use sql
> parameter instead)** the sql code to be executed (templated)

Your t1 should look like this after applying the suggestions I mentioned above.

```
t1 = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq_recent_questions_query',
        sql="""
        select * from `bigquery.table.projectid.dataset_id.table_A`;
        """,
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        destination_dataset_table=dataset_id.table_B)
```

See this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/samples/composer-bigquery#code-sample) for a sample usage of BigQueryOperator.